# Django stopped finding application static files

Tags: django

I have a Django 1.9.8 app that's working most of the times. For some reason, Django stopped service application static files, including those of the build-in admin application.

Running `collectstatic` only looks for files in my `STATICFILES_DIR`, as does `findstatic`.

I do have `django.contrib.staticfiles` in my `INSTALLED_APPS`, and yet - Django does not look for its apps' static files.

I'm stumped and don't even know where to look next.

Comment: did you update any pip-installed packages lately or make any changes to your settings file?

Comment: Settings is intact. I did install new packages, yes.

Comment: I deleted the virtual env and recreated it - it's working now. Stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was fixed by deleting the virtual environment and creating it again (without upgrading anything).

Hope this saves someone some time in the future.